# Getting json data from imgur.com

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was trying to get json data from imgur.com

To get it one has to hit this link :

```
http://imgur.com/user/{Username}/index/newest/page/{pagecount}/hit.json?scrolling
```

Where Username and pagecount may change. So i did something like this :

```
import urllib2, json
Username="Tighe"
count = 0
url = "http://imgur.com/user/"+arg+"/index/newest/page/"+str(count)+"/hit.json?scrolling"
print("URL " +url)
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = response.read()
```

I get the data but now to convert it to json format I did something like this :

```
jsonData = json.loads(data)
```

Now , it give error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "imgur_battle.py", line 8, in battle
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1214, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1187, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse(buffering=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1045, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 409, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 373, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
httplib.BadStatusLine: ''
```

Comment: Please show what `data` looks like

Comment: @Ryan http://imgur.com/user/Tighe/index/newest/page/0/hit.json?scrolling

Comment: Your problem isn't related to the JSON part, but to the request part (`httplib.BadStatusLine`).

Comment: @robertklep What you mean? I didnt get you

Comment: That the request is failing for some reason. The code as you post it works okay for me, including parsing the JSON data.

Comment: @mat7: Shouldn't the Url be `url = "http://imgur.com/user/"+Username+"/index/newest/page/"+str(count)+"/hit.json?scrolling"`

Comment: Using as URL the link you told to Ryan comments above, it works for me without any problem.

Comment: ... Also worked for me; the `json.loads` loaded the data sucessfully

Comment: @yzT Can you share your code ?

Comment: @Vaulstein What change you had done to url ?

Comment: @mat7 check the answer, I can't paste the code as a comment

Comment: instead of `arg`, I have used `Username`

Comment: Is this your entire program?

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib2, json

username = "Tighe"
count = 0
url = "http://imgur.com/user/"+username+"/index/newest/page/"+str(count)+"/hit.json?scrolling"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = response.read()
jsonData = json.loads(data)
print jsonData
```

this work without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

The only issue seems to be that you are using the `arg` variable instead of `Username` when you build the URLs. I got a `NameError`, so if you didn't presumably you have `arg` set to some extraneous value.